# Distinct triple sums

Tags: python, performance, combinatorics

Here is my code. It works fine but I need to make the code more efficient.

```
def o(s):
    l=len(s)
    return len(set([a+b+c
                    for a in s for b in s for c in s])
               )==l*(l+1)*(l+2)//6
M=int(input())
N=3**M
i=1
s=M*[i]
while i:
    if s[i]-N:
        s[i]=s[i]+1
        if o(s[:i+1]):
            if i<M-1:
                i=i+1
                s[i]=s[i-1]
            else:
                N=s[-1]
    else:
        i=i-1
print(N)
```

Note: Input should be between 1 and 12.  For the inputs 2,3,4 the code is efficient, but for inputs more than 4, it is taking too much time to run. How can I improve this?

Comment: @Dilini: Have you profiled it?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do with this code?

Comment: If you want constructive answers to Python questions you should try writing the code in a readable style. Use good names for variables. For example instead of `l`, write `length`. It means that people can read your code. Without doing this people won't even bother taking the time to figure out what your code is trying to express.

Comment: If it's really important to get performance, then write it in C/C++ and bind python to it.

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear what this code is supposed to do. How can you possibly expect us to help you improve it if we can't understand it?

For example, consider the function `o`. It takes a collection of numbers, \$s\$ (with length \$l\$), iterates over all triples \$a, b, c\$ of three elements from \$s\$ (with repetition), counts the number of distinct sums \$ a + b + c \$, and returns `True` if the number of distinct sums is equal to \$ l+2 \choose 3\$.

So for example, if you call `o([2, 3, 4])` then the set of distinct sums will be { \$ 2+2+2 = 6 \$, \$2+2+3 = 7\$, \$2+2+4 = 8\$, \$2+3+4 = 9\$, \$2+4+4 = 10\$, \$3+4+4 = 11\$, \$4+4+4 = 12\$ }, which has length 7, but \$ l+2 \choose 3\$ is 10, so `o([2, 3, 4])` returns `False`.

This seems like a strange function to want to compute. What is your motivation here? Maybe you have made a mistake and you really wanted to compute something else? How can we possibly help you when it's not clear what you want?

Let me try to reverse engineer this function. When does `o` return `True`? Well, the number of sums of three numbers chosen with repetition from a collection of length \$l\$ is:

$$ \eqalign{ { l \choose 3 } + l (l − 1) + l 
 &= { l (l − 1) (l − 2) \over 6 } + l (l − 1) + l \\
 &= { l (l + 1) (l + 2) \over 6 } \\
 &= { l + 2 \choose 3 } }$$

So `o` returns `True` if and only if all sums of three numbers chosen from \$s\$ (with repetition) are distinct. So why didn't you say so in the first place? All you had to do was to choose a good name for your function and write a [docstring](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings) and maybe a comment. Like this:

```
def distinct_triple_sums(s):
    """Return True if all sums of three items chosen with repetition from
    the sequence 's' are distinct.

    """
    # If the length of s is l, then there are C(l, 3) + l(l-1) + l =
    # C(l + 2, 3) different ways to choose three items from s with
    # repetition.
    # ... implementation here ...
```

What about the rest of the code? What does that do? Well, I added the line `print(i, s[:i+1], o(s[:i+1]))` in there, and this is the output when `M` is 3:

```
1 [1, 2] True
2 [1, 2, 3] False
2 [1, 2, 4] False
2 [1, 2, 5] True
1 [1, 3] True
2 [1, 3, 4] False
2 [1, 3, 5] False
1 [1, 4] True
2 [1, 4, 5] True
1 [1, 5] True
5
```

So it looks to me as though the original challenge must have been something like this:

> Given a number \$M\$, return the smallest number \$N\$ such that there exists a set \$S\$ of \$M\$ numbers between \$1\$ and \$N\$ inclusive such that all sums of three numbers from \$S\$ (chosen with repetition) are distinct.

Is that right? And is Fawar right to say that this is a live [IEEEXtreme](http://www.ieee.org/membership_services/membership/students/competitions/xtreme/index.html) problem? If so, it seems a bit remiss for you not to mention that.

Comment: It is.... im doing the competition and trying to understand part of the code I ended up on this post...